# How to Allow download of .cs files from asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Having a website running on godaddy server, It is having C# tutorials and associated code file with .cs extension.

What i am trying to do is , on click of download button it should trigger download of **.cs file.**
But it is giving me following error

Localhost Error:

> *This type of page is not served. Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.
>   The extension '.cs' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below
>   and make sure that it is spelled correctly.  Requested URL:
>   /WebSite1/SimpleHandler.cs*

Please tell me how to remove this error.

Comment: any particular reason you want to use only cs file to be downloaded. As they are only tutorial related files zip them and then give downloads.

Comment: Yes , i can give zip files directly but i am giving .cs files directly because search engine crawls code files & index them too ..

Comment: So the only possible way you can do it removing the extension from cs to plain text file

Comment: changing the extension to .txt will leads to have text file open in new window that would be fine. but i can't change the extension

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make two changes:

1) Allow requestFiltering in IIS global config file

Change the global config file: %systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

```
<section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

2) Allow downloading .cs file in the site's web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <!-- Very important, the IIS configuration must have the 
           overrideModeDefault to allow in the file  
           %systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config -->
      <!-- section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Allow" /> -->
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
          <remove fileExtension=".cs" />
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    ...
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: overrideModeDefault="Allow" is not allowed in web.config file on my website.. instead can i use allowOverride="true" ? but it is also showing error of unrecognized attribute.

Comment: @user1491927 overrideModeDefault is in the global applicationHost.config, not in the site's web.config